# Run script on start lua interpreter

Tags: lua, startup

How i can automatically run some script on lua without bat/shortcut, when i start interpreter? M.b. lua have some reserved file names like autorun or autoexec?

Just skip following text. Its for validator.

Comment: checkout LUA_INIT, LUA_INIT_5_2 and LUA_INIT_5_3 env variables

Comment: [How to create auto-load script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916510/how-to-create-new-commands-in-the-lua-interpreter/41916971#comment71019298_41916971)

Comment: Egor Skriptunoff, unfortunately that solution not for me, because i need it for portable use.

Answer (score -1):

For portable use you can create bat file. Its dont like to me, but it works:

```
luajit.exe %~dp0%~n0.lua
```

that .bat run script with same name.
my_name.bat - run my_name.lua
123.bat - run 123.lua

Its not perfect but idk another decision.